# Set initial growth size for database using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2012, powershell-4.0

I'm currently creating a database with PowerShell like this:

```
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($server, $database)
$db.Collation = "...";
...

$db.Create()
```

Now my question is: how to set the initial sizes for data and log files and their respective growth sizes?

I tried the following so far:

```
foreach ($fg in $db.FileGroups) {
  foreach($f in $fg) {
      $f.Size = $initialDataFileSizeInKB
      $f.Growth = $dataFileGrowthInKB
      $f.GrowthType = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FileGrowthType]::KB
    }
  }
}

foreach($lf in $db.LogFiles) {
    $lf.Size = $initialLogFileSizeInKB
    $lf.Growth = $logFileGrowthInKB
    $lf.GrowthType = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FileGrowthType]::KB
}
```

However, that does not work - problem seems to be that there are no files or log files yet. How to set the default values?

Comment: What's wrong with creating the databases with TSQL statements?

Comment: I'm not looking for a quick fix, I want to write a clean solution using the management objects.

Answer (score 0):

For the Growth and GrowthType modify the individual files.

```
foreach ($fg in $db.FileGroups) {
   foreach ($f in $fg.Files) {
      $f.Growth = $dataFileGrowthInKB
      $f.GrowthType = 'KB'
      $f.Alter()
   }
}
```

I'm not sure about modifying the initial size.  Have you tried setting that as part of the database creation?